# Getting error `\365\277\357\376 in the terminal

Tags: c, string, output

The task is to output every second word from the string

I made a loop to check every character in the string and while it reaches a space the boolean will change it value to the opposite so before it reaches the next space it will copy the characters from first string to the second

```
int main(void)
{
char str1[max]="Hellow my name is Tom why not today";
  char str2[max];
    int i;
    bool a=false;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(str1);i++)
    {
        if ((int)str1[i]==32)
        {
            a=!a;
        }
        if (a==true)
        {
            str2[i]=str1[i];
        }
    }
    printf ("%s\n",str2);
    return 0;

}
```

The terminal shows: `\365\277\357\376 my\365\277\357\376 isu

Comment: You don't initialize all of the destination array `str2`, and neither do you terminate it as a string.

Comment: There are many problems with this code.  It doesn't initialize the destination, it calls `strlen` for each and every character in `str1`, resulting in O(n**2) time complexity, it doesn't terminate the destination string, and it uses unnatural constructs like `if (a == true)` instead of just `if (a)`.  Bad code.

Comment: You don't have to specify initialized arrays size. char a[] = "aaa" is fully correct. You can also use ' ' character constant instead of 32

Comment: Since `' '` or `32` is an int, you do not need a cast `(int)` in comparison

Comment: @TomKarzes is it better to change the loop for this one for (i=0;str1[i]!='\0';i++)?
Also, can you please explain how to terminate the destination string.

Comment: @TomKarzes Many compilers will optimize the code so that strlen() is not called every time.  Gcc with optimizations turned on will actually remove the call since the value does not change.

Comment: @jmq It's not something anyone should rely on.  And in many cases, such an optimization isn't possible, if the compiler can't determine that the string is loopinvariant (which is almost always the case if it's a pointer passed to a function) and the loop makes a function call or assigns through another pointer that may be aliased to the string pointer.  When someone uses that idiom, it's a clear indication that they don't have any concept of algorithm complexity (or they think `strlen` is somehow constant-time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need different indexes for str1 and str2.  When 'a' is false you do not write to str2[i] for that value of i.  This will result is random data in the bytes you don't write.  This is why you see the garbage data between every 2nd word.

```
int dest_index = 0;
for (i=0;i<strlen(str1);i++)
{
    if ((int)str1[i]==32)
    {
        a=!a;
    }
    if (a==true)
    {
        str2[dest_index++]=str1[i];
    }
}
str2[dest_index] = 0;  // Null terminate the destination string
printf ("%s\n",str2);
```

Comment: I've got it, thank you!

Comment: This answer retains several problems that the original code had, particularly the call to `strlen` on every iteration of the loop.  And no, you can't assume that the compiler will move it out of the loop for you.  Maybe, under high optimization levels, but in many cases it couldn't even if it wanted to.